# Connecting to RabbitMQ service inside Docker container failing

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq

I am having trouble connecting to a dockerized RabbitMQ container. I am trying to connect to it using another docker service I wrote.

My `docker-compose.yaml` file is below:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    rabbitmq:
        hostname: "rabbitmq"
        image: "rabbitmq:3-management"
        container_name: "rabbitmq"
        ports: 
            - "5672:5672"
            - "15672:15672"
        stdin_open: true
        tty: true

    my_app:
        image: 'my-app'
        container_name: 'my-app'
        build: ./my_app
        ports: 
            - "8000:8000"
        volumes:
            - ./my_app:/src
        command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        env_file: ./common.env
        stdin_open: true
        tty: true
        depends_on: 
            - "rabbitmq"
        networks:
            - sandbox
networks:
    sandbox:
        name: sandbox_network
```

Now, my producer code looks as follows:

```
credentials = pika.PlainCredentials("guest", "guest")
        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
            pika.ConnectionParameters("rabbitmq", 5672, "/", credentials)
        )
        channel = connection.channel()

        channel.queue_declare(queue="croudie_creation")

        channel.basic_publish(exchange="", routing_key="hello", body="Hello World!")

        print(" [x] Sent 'Hello World!'")

        connection.close()
```

I keep getting the following error message:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbqIw.png)

Could someone please help me out here?

Comment: puit  `pika.ConnectionParameters("localhost", 5672, "/", credentials)` instead of ` pika.ConnectionParameters("rabbitmq", 5672, "/", credentials)`

Comment: I can't tell what error you're actually getting (just "Error message"?) but the two containers aren't on the same `networks:`.  I'd recommend deleting all of the `networks:` blocks in the whole file and trying again.

Comment: thanks both

@DavidMaze, can't believe I missed that, must be staring at the screen all day. Thanks for that it fixed my issue!